# Wirecloud, IDM Object Storage GE - MultiTenancy

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

The question pertains to the level of integration of Wirecloud into IDM and Object Storage, when it comes to getting access to shared Containers. Specifically, from a private WC instance running on FI-LAB and having integrated with FI-LAB IDM using the url http://cloud.lab.fi-ware.org/keystone/v2.0 as a keystone endpoint, I seem to be unable to retrieve all the available tenants from IDM (i just get a single one, being the user logged into from WC - say TENANT-B):

```
{"tenants":[{"enabled":true,"id":"0000000000000000000000000000EFGH","name":"TENANT-B"}]}
```

Of course, i can see that when logging into FI-LAB from the portal, the answer i get when calling  http://cloud.lab.fi-ware.org/keystone/v2.0/tenants is correct:

```
{"tenants":[{"enabled":true,"id":"0000000000000000000000000000ABCD","name":"TENANT-A"},{"enabled":true,"id":"0000000000000000000000000000EFGH","name":"TENANT-B"}]}
```

I am trying to get the tenants using the keystone.getTenant({... options ...}) call:

```js
keystone = new KeystoneAPI(keystone_url, {
    use_user_fiware_token : true
});
keystone.getTenants({
    onSuccess : onGetTenants,
    onFailure : function() {
        alert("Could not get a valid tenant list");
    }
});
```

Is multitenancy not supported natively on WC or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems that multitenancy is on its way :-)
For now, i solved it by creating an operator that asks the user's credentials and then handles explicitly all the communication with the IDM.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working now, take into account that the IdM and the Open Stack integration has changed.